# Does this function achieve a maximum or minimum?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $u$: $\mathbb{R}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and
$\lim_{x\to\infty}$ $u(x)$=$\lim_{x\to-\infty}$ $u(x)$=0. Does $u$ achieve a maximum or a minimum value on $\mathbb{R}$?

I think that $u$ does achieve a maximum or minimum. Also, what about the case where $u$=0? Does it not achieve a max or min in that case?

Thanks

Comment: Actually the value of the limit is irrelevant, take a look at  http://math.stackexchange.com/a/97832/87763

Comment: Oh, interesting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider instead $g(x)=|f(x)|$, which also satisfies $\lim_{x\rightarrow \pm \infty}g(x)=0$. This is also a continuous function and is bounded below by 0. Consider the interval $[-N,N]$, which is a closed set, so $g(x)$ achieves a maximum on it: $M_N$. Unless $g(x)=0$ for all $x$, $M_N$ is nondecreasing in $N$. On the other hand, there must be some $N_0>0$ such that $M_N$ is constant for all $N\geq N_0$ (otherwise $\lim_{x\rightarrow \pm \infty}g(x)=0$ is broken). So $g(x)$ achieves it maximum on $[-N_0,N_0]$ from which it follows that $f(x)$ achieves either a maximum or minimum.

As pointed out by Robert in the comments, it could be that $f$ only achieves one but not the other.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does.  In the case where $u = 0$ (everywhere), the minimum and maximum values are both $0$, and these are achieved everywhere.

Comment: Thanks. So if I wanted to prove that it achieves a maximum or minimum, would I have to show that the function is bounded?

Comment: That's part of it.