# Show that $f$ has at least one absolute maximum on $[0,+\infty[$

Tags: real-analysis

We have $f:\;[0,+\infty[\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $f$ a continuous function such as $f(0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=1$ and $f(x)>0,\;\forall\;x>0$. I need to show that $f$ has at least one absolute maximum on $[0,+\infty[$. I'm not sure how to prove this.

Comment: See this question as it's essentially the same: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1374972/does-this-function-achieve-a-maximum-or-minimum/1374988#1374988

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(0)$ is a global maximum, then you are done. Otherwise, there is some $y$ so that $f(y) > 1$. Since $\lim f(x) = 1$, there is some $X$ such that for all $x > X$, we have $f(x) < f(y)$.

Now consider the closed, compact interval $[0, X]$. $f$ is continuous and $[0,X]$ is compact, and thus $f$ attains a max value there.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend this function to $f:[0,+\infty]\to\mathbb R$ by defining $f(+\infty)=1$. This is still continuous, because you said $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=1$. Now, $[0,+\infty]$ is *compact*, so $f$ must achieve a maximum somewhere on $[0,+\infty]$. If a maximum is achieved at $+\infty$, it's also achieved at $0$, since $f(+\infty)=f(0)=1$. So the maximum is always achieved somewhere on $[0,+\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)\leq 1$ for all $x\geq 0$, then $f$ has a global maximum at $0$. If not, then $f(x_0)=y>1$ for some $x_0>0$. Since $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$, there exists some $M>0$ such that $x\geq M\implies f(x)<y$. Can you finish it from here?