# Prove there exists a point $\xi$ so that $f'(\xi)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, rolles-theorem

If we have a function $f(x)$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow \pm \infty} f(x) = 17 $. How can we show that $\exists \xi \in (-\infty, \infty) | f'(\xi) = 0$?

I'm wondering whether we can apply Rolles Theorem in this case, because now we've got an infinite interval for which our function is continous?

Thank you.

Comment: Using the intermediate value property of the derivative, all you have to show is that somewhere the derivative is positive and somewhere it is negative.   So prove a function cannot be strictly increasing or strictly decreasing if the tails have the same limit

Comment: It is a consequence of  [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97817/minimum-and-maximum-problem?noredirect=1)

Comment: @Alan But in order to use the intermediate value property of the derivative, the derivative has to be continous, right? And the information doesn't state whether f'(x) is continous or not. We only get information about that f(x) is continous, as it's differentiable. So, can I really apply it here?

Comment: @ArcticChar Thanks, it seems like something I'll be able to use.

Comment: @Tanamas No, even if the derivative is discontinuous it has the intermediate value property.  (all continuous functions have the IVP, but not all IVP functions are continuous) https://teachingcalculus.com/2014/08/18/darbouxs-theorem/

Comment: @Tanamas Some other notes, the wiki is good: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)#Darboux_function  An evil example of a Darboux function which is nowhere continuous: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function

Comment: @Alan Thanks for all links, I appreciate it. Didn't actually know about those things before :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)=17$ then $f'(x)=0$ and we are done. If not, let $x_0$ be a point such that $f(x_0)\neq 17$. Assume that $f(x_0)>17$ (the logic is the same if $f(x_0)<17$. By assumption, we know there exists $M>0$ such that $x\geq M$ implies $|f(x)-17|\leq \frac{f(x_0)-17}{2}$ and $x\leq -M$ implies $|f(x)-17|\leq \frac{f(x_0)-17}{2}$. Importantly, note that

$$f(M),f(-M)\in \left[17-\frac{f(x_0)-17}{2},17+\frac{f(x_0)-17}{2} \right]$$

By the mean value theorem, there exists $x_1\in (x_0,M]$ and $x_2\in [-M,x_0)$ such that

$$f(x_1)=17+\frac{f(x_0)-17}{2}$$

$$f(x_2)=17+\frac{f(x_0)-17}{2}$$

Then by Rolle's Theorem there exists $x_3\in (x_2,x_1)$ such that $f'(x_3)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can understand every part except from where you got that $|f(x) -17| \leq \frac{f(x_0)-17}{2}$. Could you explain that part? Is it from the epsilon delta definition, and why do you then divide it by 2?

Comment: Yes, this is an $\varepsilon$ argument. In this case, I set $\varepsilon=\frac{f(x_0)-17}{2}$ and then $M$ is the $M$ in the definition of limits at infinity. I divide by $2$ just so the argument works later (really just so $x_2<x_0<x_1$)

Comment: I see, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay: If $f$ is constant, this is trivial. Else your function needs to have at least one local extremum. That is clear: If for any interval $[a,b]$ $f$ takes it’s extreme values only in $a$ and $b$, then you have that either $f(a)< f(x) < f(b)$ or $f(a) > f(x) > f(b)$. For $x\in(a,b)$. If this holds for all $a,b$ then it is easy to see from continuity that in fact one of these equations holds for all $a,b$ and thus $f$ would be strictly monotonous or antitonous, which of course cannot happen.

So thus $f$ has at least one local extremum $x$, which implies $f'(x)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, appreciate it. It's clear to me :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the IVP in the comments,  it's pretty simple.  If your function is constant, you are done.  Assume $f'(x)>0$ and nonconstant,  that means for some $f(c)$,  $f(c)\neq 17$.  But then it being strictly increasing means that if $f(c)>17$ then for all $x>c$,  $f(x)>f(c)>17$, so you are bound away from 17 and thus contradicts the limit.  Otherwise the same thing only to negative infinity.  Reverse the two for strictly decreasing.  Thus it can't be strictly increasing or decreasing, so you have a + and a - value, and the IVP gives you a 0

Comment: Thank you, this was also very clear to me :)